# How to order list of string based on StatrtWith using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, sql-order-by

I have a list of strings shows below. I want to sort the name based on the Start with value. I try some cases but fails.
Example 
List has data like,

```
name: "Bible Reading", 
name: "Scripture Reading",
name: "Ready Set", 
name: "Career Readings",
name: "Reading-Berks"
```

I pass the queryValue as "read"  but I can not be ordering based on  the values.

```
IOrderedEnumerable<string> name = result.Select(x => x.name)
                                        .OrderBy(i => i.StartsWith(queryValue));
```

The expected output,

```
name: "Ready Set",
name: "Reading-Berks"
name: "Bible Reading", 
name: "Scripture Reading",
name: "Career Readings",
```

Comment: What did you try? How are you ordering right now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is a issue about case sensitivity.

replace

```
.OrderBy(i => i.StartsWith(queryValue));
```

with

```
.OrderByDescending(i => i.StartsWith(queryValue, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
```

because `"Ready Set".StartsWith("read")` will return false

Comment: Thanks. Its working now, FYI use "OrderByDescending: instead of orderby

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `OrderByDescending` and case insensitive comparison for the required result, hence your query will be like the following:

```
IOrderedEnumerable<string> name = result.Select(x => x.name)
                                        .OrderByDescending(i =>i.StartsWith(queryValue,StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
```

Here is a [working example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/yorA4j) which will distinguish  `OrderByDescending` and `OrderBy` for this example